# Payment or pay for?

Tags: expressions

As I work in restaurant, which one sounds better  when asking what method do they like to pay ? " how would you like to make a payment?" Or " how would you like to pay for?( to pay or pay for)" For me the former sounds more formal doesn't it? Need anyone helps!

Comment: 'How would you like to pay ?' was the wording I used to use when I worked in retail.

Comment: Which payment method do you prefer? Anything but a chirpy "And how will you be paying today?"

Comment: What kind of restaurant? 5 star or McDonald's? If the latter, "cash or charge" should work.

Comment: @Cascabel Offtopic, but is the Forbes rating really that much used in the US, or is the "five star restaurant" thing just something that people use because of the standard international 5-star based _hotel_ rating system? As a European, I am used to the Michelin rating which certainly doesn't go further than 3 stars.

Comment: @oerkelens Sorry, but I live in a third world country (Guatemala). Really have no idea. In my country, MacDonald's is a career. We really need a lot more context in this question.

Comment: Quite honestly, even in places far more upscale than McDonald's, I'd be likely to hear 'Will that be cash or charge/credit?', except in the most expensive places, where they're likely to assume credit/charge.

Answer (score 1):

"How would you like to make a payment?" most certainly sounds more formal, you're correct! "How would you like to pay?" also works if you're trying to sound more casual.

Comment: "How would you like to make a payment?" sounds detached, almost cold.  It isn't incorrect, just maybe something you'd expect to see written on a website or hear in an automated message recording.  I agree, it would probably be better to use the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say "How would you like to pay sir/madam?"